# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 error only on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, xml, windows-server-2012, xmldocument, windows-server-2012-r2

When I try to call `XmlDocument.LoadXml` I get the below error,

It only happens on `Windows Server 2012 R2` I have tried on three of them, and it's fine on `Windows Server 2008 R2`

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
```

I have seen similar posts on SO, and I have done removing BOM at the beginning, but still the same

This is the code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Without BOM
        var str = "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjxhY2NvdW50PjwvYWNjb3VudD4=";
        Console.WriteLine("Base64 string without BOM:\r\n{0}", str);
        Console.WriteLine("String without BOM:\r\n{0}", str.FromBase64ToUnicode());

        Console.WriteLine();

        //With BOM
        str = "77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjxhY2NvdW50PjwvYWNjb3VudD4=";
        Console.WriteLine("Base64 string with BOM:\r\n{0}", str);
        Console.WriteLine("String with BOM:\r\n{0}", str.FromBase64ToUnicode());
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string FromBase64ToUnicode(this string s, bool removePreamble = true)
    {
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
        string unicode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

        if (!removePreamble)
        {
            return unicode;
        }

        string byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
        Console.WriteLine("unicode.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8):{0}", unicode.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8));
        return unicode.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8) ? unicode.Remove(0, byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length) : unicode;
    }
}
```

Windows Server 2008R2
[image]

Windows Server 2012R2
[image]

### update

It seems that the way that we have removed `BOM` is not working on `Server 2012R2`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], even if it only fails on that one box?

Comment: Is this a web application?  Are you loading the XML from a file? Any way you could load it with a string reader and include it with the exception?  2012r2 has a significantly different security model, it's possible you're trying to parse some sort of server error page as XML, or possibly nothing at all.

Comment: I'm trying really hard, but I can't quite teleport myself to your computer so I can examine the XML and look at your code. It's probably the weather here (we're experiencing some thunderstorms that are expected to last a few hours) - maybe in the meantime you could provide the details here instead to save some time.

Comment: It looks like you removed any characters invalid character at the beginning  of the file.  So I suspecting an encoding issue.  If you open the xml file in NotePad and then try saving using 'Save As' you will see in the dialog an Encoding DropDown box.  Try setting Encoding to ANSI.  You are using LoadXml(string)l which expects a string (not a file).  Use Load(filename) instead if you are reading from a file

Comment: @MiniverCheevy The string is read from Request

Comment: @KenWhite question is updated

Comment: @JonSkeet question is updated